# the position vector $x(t_0)$ is orthogonal to the velocity vector $x'(t_0)$ if $x(t_0)$ is the point on the image of $x$ closest to the origin .

Tags: calculus, analysis, multivariable-calculus, vector-spaces, vector-analysis

Let $x(t)$ be a path of class $C^1$ that does not pass through the origin in $R^3$. If $x(t_0)$ is the point on the image of $x$ closest to the origin and $x'(t_0)\neq 0$, show that the position vector $x(t_0)$ is orthogonal to the velocity vector $x'(t_0)$.

Define the function $f(t)=x(t)\cdot x(t)$, then if the function attains its minimum at an interior point of the domain, $f'(t_0)=2x(t_0)\cdot x'(t_0)=0$, so we can get the desired result. However, my question is what if the domain of the path is a closed interval of the form $[a,b]$. Then the minimum may occur at the endpoints, in which case we can't use the interior extremum theorem. 
How can the result still be guaranteed in such general cases?

Answer (score 1):

Consider: $$x: [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3:t \rightarrow (1+t,0,0) $$
The point closest to the origin is $x(0)$ but the velocity (wich we now see as the right derivative of $x$) is not $0$.

Comment: So are you suggesting that the problem only makes sense when we consider open intervals as domain?

Comment: Yes indeed, if the domain is open. Suppose that $x$ attains a minimum distance from the origin. Then we know that the derivative of $||x(t)||$ is $0$ at the minimum. This is because if we let $t$ go a bit to the right of the minimum, the distance has to increase. So the derivative is positive. If we let t go negative, the distance has to increase to. So the derivative is also negative. Thus the derivative equals $0$. This consideration is not possible at endpoints because we can only let $t$ change in one direction.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But are the conditions of $C^1$ and the derivative nonzero necessary for the statement? Isn't differentiability enough?

Comment: Yes differentiablility is enough.